# preg_match_all possible variations

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I like to know up to three parts of a string. The string can be either

`{identifier}`, `{identifier:foo}`, `{identifier:foo|bar}` or `{identifier|bar}`

The string can occur multiple times in `$content` this is why is use `preg_match_all`

Currently I have

```
preg_match_all( '#\{'.preg_quote($identifier).':?([^\}|]+)?\|?([^\}]+)?\}#i', $content, $matches );
```

which work for <del>the very first</del> all versions except `{identifier|bar}` <del>but not for the others</del>.

Edit:

`$matches` should look like this (with a single appearance in `$content`)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {timezone:foo|bar}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => bar
        )

)
```

Comment: Its easy to make those all of those with a single expression.  But how do you want the structure of `$matches` to look?

Comment: I don't understand, is working for me: http://regex101.com/r/yS9uK0/1

Comment: yes, only `{identifier|bar}` doesn't work in my case

Comment: are you sure you want to use `identifier|bar` not `identifier:bar`?

Comment: Anyway, the given pattern is working me for anything between: `{}`

Comment: Problem was caused by another issue in the application

Comment: Sorry, guys - as @Leandro mentioned this works just fine, the problem was somewhere else in the app